# Customizing jquery theme for different component

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There are different UI jQuery components available. If I am using a particular jQuery theme and I want to customize the css of any UI component (for example jQuery tab)

My question is how to customize the css of jQuery tab without affecting other components?

The problem I am facing is if I customize the tab css, my css change is partially affecting other components.

Answer (score 2):

Use a special namespace class... for example `mytabs` and apply it to a container element. then redefine the themeing classes with this namespace to override... for example:

```
.mytabs .ui-tabs {}
.mytabs .ui-tab {}
```

so on and so forth.

Comment: Where should i refer "mytabs" in the js?

Comment: Not in JS, this is in CSS. You shouldnt need to override any js if youre jsut changing the visual styling.